# iOS 11.3 WKWebView: input.focus() doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, wkwebview

Since updating to iOS 11.3, HTML input fields cannot be focused anymore using JavaScript .focus() except when the function call is immediately following a touch interaction (it used to be possible to use .focus() at any time). Is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Adding click function to the element to invoke focus function just works fine. Or any better solution?

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, email=no">            
</head>
<body>
    <input id="test" type="text" placeholder="test" />
    <input id="test2" type="text" placeholder="test" />

    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.FastClick.attach(document.body);
        document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(e) {
          // works fine
          e.target.focus();
        };
        document.getElementById('test2').onclick = function(e) {
          // not working
          setTimeout(function() {
            e.target.focus();
          }, 50)
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer

Comment: Just add onclick to trigger focus

Answer (score 2):

call `blur()` before `focus()`.....

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code we currently use in our app development framework to make input.focus() work. Confirmed to be working and accepted in the App Store by Apple:

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"WKContentView");
NSOperatingSystemVersion iOS_11_3_0 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){11, 3, 0};
NSOperatingSystemVersion iOS_12_2_0 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){12, 2, 0};
NSOperatingSystemVersion iOS_13_0_0 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){13, 0, 0};

if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion: iOS_13_0_0]) {
    SEL selector = sel_getUid("_elementDidFocus:userIsInteracting:blurPreviousNode:activityStateChanges:userObject:");
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
    IMP original = method_getImplementation(method);
    IMP override = imp_implementationWithBlock(^void(id me, void* arg0, BOOL arg1, BOOL arg2, BOOL arg3, id arg4) {
    ((void (*)(id, SEL, void*, BOOL, BOOL, BOOL, id))original)(me, selector, arg0, TRUE, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    });
    method_setImplementation(method, override);
}
else if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion: iOS_12_2_0]) {
    SEL selector = sel_getUid("_elementDidFocus:userIsInteracting:blurPreviousNode:changingActivityState:userObject:");
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
    IMP original = method_getImplementation(method);
    IMP override = imp_implementationWithBlock(^void(id me, void* arg0, BOOL arg1, BOOL arg2, BOOL arg3, id arg4) {
    ((void (*)(id, SEL, void*, BOOL, BOOL, BOOL, id))original)(me, selector, arg0, TRUE, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    });
    method_setImplementation(method, override);
}
else if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion: iOS_11_3_0]) {
    SEL selector = sel_getUid("_startAssistingNode:userIsInteracting:blurPreviousNode:changingActivityState:userObject:");
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
    IMP original = method_getImplementation(method);
    IMP override = imp_implementationWithBlock(^void(id me, void* arg0, BOOL arg1, BOOL arg2, BOOL arg3, id arg4) {
        ((void (*)(id, SEL, void*, BOOL, BOOL, BOOL, id))original)(me, selector, arg0, TRUE, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    });
    method_setImplementation(method, override);
} else {
    SEL selector = sel_getUid("_startAssistingNode:userIsInteracting:blurPreviousNode:userObject:");
    Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
    IMP original = method_getImplementation(method);
    IMP override = imp_implementationWithBlock(^void(id me, void* arg0, BOOL arg1, BOOL arg2, id arg3) {
        ((void (*)(id, SEL, void*, BOOL, BOOL, id))original)(me, selector, arg0, TRUE, arg2, arg3);
    });
    method_setImplementation(method, override);
}
```

Comment: Hello Seven, can you tell me where exactly in your code base you inserted these lines? Thank you.

Comment: Hello Louis -- right after initializing the WKWebView. However, the code has been extended for newer iOS versions since then... will update it now.

Comment: Swizzling a private method like this is a bad idea. E.g. Ionic framework does the same thing, and it broke in our app in iPadOS 16.3 (i.e. any single tap in our app would bring up the keyboard).

It's bad because (a) it's bad practice to even think of calling much less swizzling a private method or private class in an Apple framework, and (b) it might one day get you rejected by the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they have been pushed some updates to the repo:

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/pull/171#issuecomment-377824347

So make sure you remove cordova ios platform, add the latest version of the wkwebview: cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.19 and than add npm install and add platform ios. I've just tested it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm not using Cordova, but I've already found the new way to sizzle (or was it swizzle?) the relevant WebKit functions after much Googling. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @SevenSystems could you please share a solution that you've found? We don't use Cordova either and stuck with the issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on a terrible hack like swizzling a private method in an Apple Framework, the best you can probably do is file this as a bug with Apple.

Do a Spotlight search for "Feedback Assistant.app" and log in with your Apple Dev credentials, then file a ticket against iOS WebKit.